# Calculating if day has passed based on time difference and insert updated date if it has

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

EDIT: Solution is not possible, need to think of a better workaround.

I am scraping this webpage (http://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl-2017-2018/results/#/page/6/) and am trying to insert the date of the game (in gray on page) into each respective game time row.

I am struggling with how to achieve this logic.

The list of scraped dates for this page is as follows...

```
file_days=[['17 Sep 2017'],['15 Sep 2017'],['12 Sep 2017'], ['11 Sep 2017'],['10 Sep 2017'], ['08 Sep 2017'],['01 Sep 2017'],['31 Aug 2017'],
           ['28 Aug 2017'],['27 Aug 2017'],['26 Aug 2017'],['25 Aug 2017'],['24 Aug 2017']]

file_days=file_days[::-1]
```

I am trying to insert these dates into the following dataframe that contains each scraped games start time.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'game_time': ['23:00','23:30','23:00','00:00','23:00','23:00','23:00','23:30','23:30','00:00','00:00','00:00','01:00','17:00','20:30','00:00','23:00','23:00','23:00','23:00',                 '23:00','23:30','23:30','23:30','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:00','00:30','01:00','02:00','02:00','00:30','17:00','17:00','17:00','17:00','17:00','17:00','17:00','17:00','20:05','20:25','20:25','00:30','23:10','02:20','00:25','17:00','17:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

So far I have the following code, but I just can't seem to figure out the logic of trying to insert a new date if the time has passed to a new day.

```
df.game_time = pd.to_datetime(df.game_time)
df['game'] = df.game_time.dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df['previous_game'] = df.game_time.dt.strftime('%H:%M').shift(1)
df['previous_game'] = df['previous_game'].fillna(str('00:00'))

matchup_day = []

for a,b in zip(df['game'],df['previous_game']):
    if a >= b:
        matchup_day.append(file_days[0]) #if time of current game is greater than time of previous game than use the current date

    else:
        matchup_day.append(file_days[1]) #if time of current game is less than time of previous game, then use the next date and delete the most recently used date
        file_days.pop(0)
```

The output of this is as follows...

```
 matchup_day
 [['24 Aug 2017'],
 ['24 Aug 2017'],
 ['25 Aug 2017'],
 ['26 Aug 2017'],
 ['26 Aug 2017'],
 ['26 Aug 2017'],
 ['26 Aug 2017'],
 ['26 Aug 2017'],
 ['26 Aug 2017'],
 ['27 Aug 2017'],
 ['27 Aug 2017'],
 ['27 Aug 2017'],
 ['27 Aug 2017'],
 ['27 Aug 2017'],
 ['27 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['28 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['31 Aug 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['01 Sep 2017'],
 ['08 Sep 2017'],
 ['08 Sep 2017'],
 ['10 Sep 2017'],
 ['11 Sep 2017'],
 ['11 Sep 2017'],
 ['11 Sep 2017']]
```

This output is clearly incorrect as it gets tripped up at row 15 of the dataframe, or the 28th of August on the website. Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve this logic?

I am also open to completely different ideas on how to achieve this as well.
Thank you in advance as I have been quite stumped by this.

Comment: I think you are approaching the problem from wrong side. Don't try to merge already scraped data. Scrape them in such way that you get properly structured data in the first place.

Comment: Ok yeah thank you I was kind of thinking that as well. Maybe I need to just revisit my script and figure out a way to insert each table header correctly based on the number of games for that date. The only other thought I had was if Python had a way of calculating the date based on knowing the beginning date. Eg if a day has passed based on time, insert the next date.

Comment: Please don’t gut your own questions here in the way you did in the edit at https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52580706/4. Instead just add some kind of note to the question indicating *“I now realize this question is incomplete and not answerable in its current form.”* or whatever.

Comment: Sounds good will do from here on in, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a manual loop here. You can compare a series to a shifted version for itself, then use [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and map via dictionary.

Here's a demo:

```
from itertools import chain

file_days = [['17 Sep 2017'], ['15 Sep 2017'], ['12 Sep 2017'], ['11 Sep 2017'],
             ['10 Sep 2017'], ['08 Sep 2017'], ['01 Sep 2017'], ['31 Aug 2017'],
             ['28 Aug 2017'], ['27 Aug 2017'], ['26 Aug 2017'], ['25 Aug 2017'],
             ['24 Aug 2017']]

d = dict(enumerate(chain.from_iterable(file_days[::-1])))

df['date'] = (df['game'] < df['game'].shift()).cumsum().map(d)
```

Result:

```
print(df[['game', 'date']])

     game         date
0   23:00  24 Aug 2017
1   23:30  24 Aug 2017
2   23:00  25 Aug 2017
3   00:00  26 Aug 2017
4   23:00  26 Aug 2017
5   23:00  26 Aug 2017
6   23:00  26 Aug 2017
7   23:30  26 Aug 2017
8   23:30  26 Aug 2017
9   00:00  27 Aug 2017
10  00:00  27 Aug 2017
11  00:00  27 Aug 2017
12  01:00  27 Aug 2017
13  17:00  27 Aug 2017
14  20:30  27 Aug 2017
15  00:00  28 Aug 2017
16  23:00  28 Aug 2017
17  23:00  28 Aug 2017
18  23:00  28 Aug 2017
19  23:00  28 Aug 2017
20  23:00  28 Aug 2017
21  23:30  28 Aug 2017
22  23:30  28 Aug 2017
23  23:30  28 Aug 2017
24  00:00  31 Aug 2017
25  00:00  31 Aug 2017
26  00:00  31 Aug 2017
27  00:00  31 Aug 2017
28  00:30  31 Aug 2017
29  01:00  31 Aug 2017
30  02:00  31 Aug 2017
31  02:00  31 Aug 2017
32  00:30  01 Sep 2017
33  17:00  01 Sep 2017
34  17:00  01 Sep 2017
35  17:00  01 Sep 2017
36  17:00  01 Sep 2017
37  17:00  01 Sep 2017
38  17:00  01 Sep 2017
39  17:00  01 Sep 2017
40  17:00  01 Sep 2017
41  20:05  01 Sep 2017
42  20:25  01 Sep 2017
43  20:25  01 Sep 2017
44  00:30  08 Sep 2017
45  23:10  08 Sep 2017
46  02:20  10 Sep 2017
47  00:25  11 Sep 2017
48  17:00  11 Sep 2017
49  17:00  11 Sep 2017
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but it looks like it's not getting all of the dates? For instance, the website/code I pasted goes until September 17th, and your output looks to stop on the 11th of September.  Hopefully this is an easy fix?

Comment: @CamG, That just means the dates don't pass through enough days. Which row do you suggest the logic should change to "the next day" where it's not doing so now?

Comment: It looks like it starts getting hung up on row 16, that date should be the beginning 31st of August, but it continues using the 28th of August for the next few rows it looks like

Comment: Seems fine to me. `23:00` is *after* `00:00`. Then rows 16-20 all have the same time. How are we  meant to know which ones are the next day?

Comment: great question haha, I think there is a major flaw in my logic here and it is time for me to go back to the drawing board and just add the date to my scraper (sigh).  Thank you for the help though.  Do I still give you the answer even though there probably isn't  a solution to my question?

Comment: @CamG, You should accept it only if you found it helpful. It does show how you vectorise a `for` loop approach. You should also edit your question to state that it's incomplete - so others don't spend more time on it.

Comment: works for me, definitely learned something new today so will do.  How do I go about marking as incomplete?  Do I just simply edit it?

Comment: @CamG, You should ask a new question including, of course, a reproducible problem. The good news is you're half way there, you just need to figure out the logic that you need to implement.